# how to be notified in view in Databinding library?

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-databinding

Hi my problem is that my activity listening for `viewmodel` field changes but callback not get called!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "changed");
        }
    });
    User user = new User("user");
    binding.setUser(user);
    user.setName("newUser");
    }

}
```

and my viewModel:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {

    public String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

}
```

UI updated but callback not get called. I want a callback plus UI update.
I want to know data binding library works like this! there is Libraries like Rxjava for this but I don't like to import it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
binding.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "changed");
    }
});
User user = new User("user");
binding.setUser(user);
user.setName("newUser");
```

You should receive one notification on the callback you provided and it should be received when you call `binding.setUser(user)`. Look for `ActivityMainBinding.java` and you will see the code generated for the class in your app's build folder. In the `setUser()` method, you'll see the call to `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.user)` that will call your listener.

The problem you're seeing is that the data change you want (name) is happening on the *User* and not on the *Binding*. In order to get notifications on changes to the user, you must add a lister like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
User user = new User("user");
user.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "changed");
    }
});
binding.setUser(user);
user.setName("newUser");
```

Anything implementing the `Observable` interface will support any number of listeners, so you can feel free to listen for events.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to get the callback when you called `setUser` ? Because that's not the way it works. `setUser` explicitly sets the data model views on the bound views. The property change callback would be invoked if you change the value of any of the data model properties beyond this point. Change your code to this and i guess you would get the callback -

```
User user = new User("sa");
binding.setUser(user);
user.setName("Johny Depp");   //you should receive the callback beyond this and the UI would update too
```

**Edit  -** 
A class implementing the Observable interface will allow the binding to attach a single listener to a bound object to listen for changes of all properties on that object.

The Observable interface has a mechanism to add and remove listeners, but notifying is up to the developer. To make development easier, a base class, BaseObservable, was created to implement the listener registration mechanism. The data class implementer is still responsible for notifying when the properties change. This is done by assigning a Bindable annotation to the getter and notifying in the setter.

Comment: not really, `addOnPropertyChangedCallback` is called on `ActivityMainBinding` object (ActivityMainBinding binding), so `onPropertyChanged` will be ONLY called after `binding.setUser(...)`

Comment: sry but there is onclick listener for a button there. but when I press the button UI updates but onPropertyChanged not get called. From " Observable interface will allow the binding to attach a single listener" you mean no other listener can attach to listener except one? and UI is that ONE?

Comment: @pskink I updated my code and this is the as previous. u tested it?